# Crear un json object para data table

Tags: php, datatables

actualmente estoy trabajando en un proyecto en donde se utiliza la librería datatable, la consulta la realizo usando PDO en donde ya me traigo el arreglo con los registros de la consulta.

Así me traigo los registros de la consulta con PDO:

```
$prep   = $this->conexion->prepare($sql);  
$prep->execute();   
$result = $prep->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


$json   = [
  "data" =>  $result
];
echo json_encode($json,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Viendo el ejemplo de la pagina [datatble](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html), el archivo que necesito maneja esta estructura:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Tiger Nixon",
      "position": "System Architect",
      "salary": "$320,800",
      "start_date": "2011/04/25",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "5421"
    },
    {
      "name": "Garrett Winters",
      "position": "Accountant",
      "salary": "$170,750",
      "start_date": "2011/07/25",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "extn": "8422"
    }
  ]
}
```

pero al usar json_encode en php solo consigo esto:

```
{
    "data":{
        "0":{
            "id":"2",
            "fch":"2017-06-28 10:33:31.033",
            "cod":"AIGI",
            "val":"",
            "val2":"123",
            "ref":"1368879",
            "cant":"521"
        },
        "1":{
            "id":"3",
            "fch":"2017-06-28 15:54:20.185",
            "cod":"AIGI",
            "val":"",
            "val2":"1234",
            "ref":"1368879",
            "cant":"521"
        }
    }
}
```

Ya probé agregando la opción JSON_FORCE_OBJECT pero sigo sin conseguirlo, de ante mano gracias por tomarse el tiempo de revisarlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ya logre solucionarlo, dejo la respuesta en caso de que a alguien mas se le presente la misma situación:

Después de obtener el arreglo con la información de la consulta, se debe realizar un ciclo en donde se almacenara el contenido del objeto data que se usara con nuestro datatable, en mi caso como yo busco algo completamente dinámico en el interior del primer ciclo, realizo otro que me toma el nombre del campo, una vez armado el arreglo con el contenido del data, realizo la creación del del array y finalizo codificando lo en json como se ve en el siguiente código:

```
$prep   = $this->conexion->prepare($sql);  
$prep->execute();   
$result = $prep->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$data   = [];
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    $InfoData=[]; 
    foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
        $InfoData[$key1] = $value1;
    }
    $data[] = $InfoData;
}

$json_data = [
    "data"   => $data   
];

echo json_encode($json_data);
```

Dándome como resultado:

```
{  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "id":"2",
         "fch":"2017-06-28 10:33:31.033",
         "cod":"AIGI",
         "val":"",
         "val2":"123",
         "ref":"1368879",
         "cant":"521"
      },
      {  
         "id":"3",
         "fch":"2017-06-28 15:54:20.185",
         "cod":"AIGI",
         "val":"",
         "val2":"123",
         "ref":"1368879",
         "cant":"521"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: bro yo necesito mostrar los datos que se estan filtrando, en un buscador personalizado, pero no sé como puedo traer la informacion de ajax con datables y pintarla en la table. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/398519/c%c3%b3mo-obtener-datos-de-db-usando-mysql-php-y-pdo-con-ajax