# ¿cómo obtener datos de db usando MySQL, PHP y PDO con AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, datatables

estoy pintando los datos en mi tabla(datatables) de la siguiente manera:
cuerpo de la tabla:

```
<?php

                            $item = null;
                            $valor= null;
                            $table="nametb";

                            $respdts = Controladortabladts::ctrMostrardts($table, $item, $valor);
                            $fila=-1;

                            foreach ($respdts as $key => $value) {

                                echo '<tr class="fila-white">

                                    <td>'.($key+1).'</td>
                                    <td>'.$value["fecha_registro"].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$value["fk_persona_resp"].'</td>';

                                    $item = "cod_mp";
                                    $valor= $value["fk_lotp"];

                                    $referencia = Controladortabledts2::ctrMostrardts2($item, $valor);

                                    echo '<td>'.$referencia["lote_p"].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$referencia["viaje"].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$value["presencia_plu"].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$value["presencia_tra"].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$value["presencia_buch"].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$value["presencia_prov"].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$value["presencia_buche_alime"].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$value["presencia_pulmones_c"].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$value["presencia_hemato"].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$value["presencia_granul"].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$value["presencia_derm"].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$value["presencia_viscer"].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$value["presencia_viscera_blan"].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$value["presencia_cloaca_c"].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$value["presencia_materia_f"].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$value["presencia_hiel_c"].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$referencia["hora_sacrifici"].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$value["hr_fin_eviscerad"].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$value["tiemp_sacrifici"].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$value["cloro_resi_ini_i"].'</td>
                                        <td>'.$value["cloro_resi_fin_i"].'</td>'
                                    ;

                                    if($usuarios2["tipo"]=="ADMIN"){

                                        echo
                                            '<td>
                                                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Third group">
                                                    <button class="btn btn-warning btnEditInsCn manito-clic" editInCn="'.$value["cod_tabledts1"].'" idUsuario="'.$usuarios2["cod_persona_resp"].'" User="'.$usuarios2["tipo_user"].'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditInsCn"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Third group">
                                                    <button class="btn btn-danger btnEliminarInsCn manito-clic" deleteInCn="'.$value["cod_tabledts1"].'" lotepiku="'.$referencia["lote_p"].'" viajepiku="'.$referencia["viaje"].'"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>'
                                        ;

                                    }

                                echo '</tr>';
                            }
                        ?>
```

aquí esta mi archivo php donde esta las consultas sql:

```
<?php
require_once "conectbd.php";
 
class Controladortabladts{
 
   /********************************************************
    SHOW DATAS
   ********************************************************/
   static public function ctrMostrardts($table, $item, $value){
 
      if($item != null){
 
         $stmt = Conexion::conect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $item = :$item");
 
         $stmt -> bindParam(":".$item, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 
         $stmt -> execute();
 
         return $stmt -> fetch();
 
      }else{
 
         $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla ORDER BY lote desc, viaje ASC");
 
         $stmt -> execute();
 
         return $stmt -> fetchAll();
      }
 
      $stmt -> close();
 
      $stmt = null;
 
 }
 
 
 
 }
// end class Controladortabladts
```

básicamente así traigo mis datos desde la bd.

pero tengo un incoveniente quiero mostrar los datos desde un archivo de ajax usando datatbles, sin perder el filtro personalizado, y todas las opciones que ofrece datatables.

es decir que cuando se busque algo en el buscador.

cuando haga table.draw().

se cargue la respuesta desde un archivo ajax, pintando todas las filas que coincidan y borrando las que se pintaron en un inicio, o en caso que se borre lo que se escribió entonces que sigan los datos iniciales.

también agrego mi código que uso para aplicar filtro personalizado.

donde necesito traer los datos atreves de ajax y pintarlos en las tabla,
con los botones editar y eliminar, usando mi functions PHP usando el metodo PDO para conectarme a la bd, y traer mis datos.

no sé si me hago entender agradecería sus ayudas.

codigo js:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
//aqui estan las reglas que debe cumplir para arojar losd atos cuando se busca por el filtro perzonalizado
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
    
        if (settings.nTable.id === 'search_all') {

            var year = String( $('#id_ano_searchPv').val(), 10 );
            var lote = String( $('#valor_a_compararPv1').val(), 10 );
            var viaje = String( $('#valor_a_compararPv2').val(), 10 );

            console.log("years: input",year);
            console.log("lote: input",lote);
            console.log("viaje: input",viaje);

            let years = data[1] || 0;
            let lotes = data[3] || 0;
            let viajes = data[4] || 0; // use data for the age column
            //console.log("viajes: ",viajes);
            var yearft = moment(years,'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss a').format('YYYY');

            if (year!="" && lote=="" && viaje=="") {
                if (yearft===year){
                    return true;
                }
            }else if (year=="" && lote!="" && viaje=="") {
                if (lotes===lote){
                    return true;
                }
            }else if (year=="" && viaje!="" && lote=="") {
                if (viajes===viaje){
                    return true;
                }
            }else if (year!="" && lote!="" && viaje!="") {
                if (yearft===year && lotes===lote && viajes===viaje){
                    return true;
                }
            }else if (year!="" && lote!="" && viaje=="") {
                if (yearft===year && lotes===lote){
                    return true;
                }
            }else if (year!="" && lote=="" && viaje!="") {
                if (yearft===year && viajes===viaje){
                    return true;
                }
            }else if (year=="" && lote!="" && viaje!="") {
                if (lotes===lote && viajes===viaje){
                    return true;
                }
            }else{
                return true
            }
        }

    }

);




/**BÚSQUEDA PERSONALIZADA PARA LA MAYORIA DE MODULOS */
$(document).ready(function(){

    var table3=$(".datatable2").DataTable({dom: 'Bfrtip',
        dom: 'Blftipr',
        buttons:[
            {
                extend:    'copy',
                text:      '<i class="fa  fa-copy"></i> ',
                title: tittleoage,
                titleAttr: 'copiar',
                className: 'btn btn-secondary'
            },
            {
                text:      '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i>',
                titleAttr: 'Exportar a Excel',
                className: 'btn btn-success',
                action: function () {

                    function doit(type, fn, dl) {
                        var elt = document.getElementById('search_all');
                        var wb = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(elt, {sheet:"RUTA"});
                        return dl ?
                        XLSX.write(wb, {bookType:type, bookSST:true, type: 'base64'}) :
                        XLSX.writeFile(wb, fn || (tittleoage+'.' + (type || 'xlsx')));
                    }

                    doit();

                    /* $('#search_all').tableExport({
                        ignoreColumn: ["noexportar"],
                        fileName: tittleoage,
                        type:'excel'
                    }); */
                }
            },
            {
                //extend:    'pdfHtml5',
                text:      '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> ',
                titleAttr: 'Exportar a PDF',
                className: 'btn btn-danger',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':not(.noexportar)'
                },
                action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                    var tittl= tittleoage;
                    var pdfsize = "a0"
                    var doc = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', pdfsize);
                    var dats=doc.autoTable({ html: '#search_all', headStyles:{valign: 'top',halign : 'center'}, styles: {lineColor: [44, 62, 80], lineWidth: 1,}});
                    console.log("dtaos tablas: ",dats);
                    doc.save(tittl+'.pdf')
                    //doc.output(tittl+'.pdf'); //it does not work
                }
            },
            {
                extend: "colvis",
                text: '<i class="fa fa-eye-slash"></i>',
                titleAttr: 'ocultar o mostrar colums',
                className: 'btn btn-secondary'
            },
            {
                text: '<i class="fa fa-eye"></i>',
                titleAttr: 'mostrar todas las colums',
                className: 'btn btn-secondary',
                action: function () {
                    table3.colReorder.reset();
                    table3.columns().visible(true, true);
                    //
                }
            }
        ],
        colReorder: true,
        keys: true,
        /*se configura el idioma de la vista en español */
        "language": {
            "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
            "sLengthMenu":     "MOSTRAR _MENU_ REGISTROS",
            "sZeroRecords":    "NO SE ENCONTRARON RESULTADOS",
            "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
            "sInfo":           "MOSTRANDO REGISTROS DEL _START_ AL _END_ DE UN TOTAL DE _TOTAL_",
            "sInfoEmpty":      "MOSTRANDO REGISTROS DEL 0 AL 0 DE UN TOTAL DE 0",
            "sInfoFiltered":   "(FILTRADO DE UN TOTAL DE _MAX_ REGISTROS)",
            "sInfoPostFix":    "",
            "sSearch":         "BUSCAR:",
            "sUrl":            "",
            "sInfoThousands":  ",",
            "sLoadingRecords": "CARGANDO...",
            "oPaginate": {
            "sFirst":    "PRIMERO",
            "sLast":     "ULTIMO",
            "sNext":     "SIGUIENTE",
            "sPrevious": "ANTERIOR"
            },
            "oAria": {
                "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
            }

        },
        /*activo la el scroll dentro de la tabla para poder depararme y obtener vista de todas las columnas-filas */
        "scrollY": 300,
        "scrollX": true,
        "columnDefs": [
            { className: "dt-body-left", "targets": [ 0 ] }
        ],
        /*aquí estoy filtrando las columnas de donde obtendré los datos cuando se escribe algo en el buscador*/
        columnDefs: [
            { targets: [1, 2, 3, 4], searchable: true},
            { targets: '_all', searchable: false }
        ]
    });

    /**BÚSQUEDA PERSONALIZADA MODULO PARA POR VIAJE Y OTROS */
    $("#search_all").ready(function() {
        table3.draw();

        // Escucha de eventos a las dos entradas de filtrado de rango para volver a dibujar en la entrada
        //cuando se escribe algo en el buscador entonces me filtra si se cumple en filtrado personalizado
        $('#id_ano_searchPv, #valor_a_compararPv1, #valor_a_compararPv2').keyup( function() {

            table3.draw();
        });

    });

 
});
```

Comment: No se termina de entender ¿cuál es el problema a resolver?, al momento no veo como ajax mejoraría el tiempo, ¿realmente necesitas obtener 8000 registros de una sola vez?

Comment: okay no necesito obtener esa cantidad, te explico quiero trear los ulitimos registros que correspondan a cierto valor cuando se cargue por primera vez la tabla, pero ofresco un filtrado perzonalizado, por eso quiero saber como puedo traer los registos usando datables, que coincida con lo que se esta buscando.

Comment: y luego pintarlos en la tabla, y si no hay nada el buscador me vuelva apintar lo que habia incialmente.

Comment: Esta pregunta está más orientada a sugerencias, te recomiendo enfocar mejor tu pregunta.

Comment: modifique mi pregunta, no sé si me hago entender.